# Using HttpWebRequest, Keep-alive not working for many similar requests to localhost

Tags: http, keep-alive, dotnet-httpclient

I'm using `HttpWebRequest` to send many **sync** requests to the **same HTTP URL** on localhost, and I need to re-use TCP connections to prevent ephemeral port depletion.

But I don't seem to be able to get Keep-alive working.

Here's my code where I make the HTTP request:

```
var request = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create(url);
HttpWebResponse response = null;

request.Method = "GET";
request.KeepAlive = true;

try
{
    response = (HttpWebResponse) request.GetResponse();
    // ...
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    // ...
}
finally
{
    if (response != null)
    {
        response.Close();
    }
}
```

I call the above code many times in a loop. All requests are successful, and return OK status code (200), but running `netstat -ano` reveals that there are MANY MANY connections in the `TIME_WAIT` state, where I expect it to re-use a single connection.

I tried calling both an IIS Express server on localhost (default ASP.NET MVC application) and a WebLogic application, with the same result.

I also tried `HttpClient` from .NET 4.5.

This quickly results in running out of ephemeral ports.

Is there anything wrong with what I'm doing? How can I make .NET re-use TCP connections?

Answer (score 0):

Try response.Dispose(); instead of response.Close();