# MyCouch client configuration and usage

Tags: couchdb, cloudant

I've a couple of questions regarding the (excellent) CouchDB .NET client [MyCouch](https://github.com/danielwertheim/mycouch/):

- Is there some built-in retry policy in case of "transient" failure (like the server responding 503)?
- Should instances of `MyCouchClient` or `MyCouchStore` be cached to be reused? Right now I'm creating one for each incoming request, but I'm wondering if that incurs a performance penalty.
- I would like to customize the configuration of Json.NET as used by MyCouch, like adding a `new StringEnumConverter { CamelCaseText = true }` to the list of `Converters`. Is there a way to achieve that through the API?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) There's no magic in the `MyCouchClient`, it's just simple requests and responses. The `MyCouchStore` how-ever, I would gladly accept pull request to have options for retries or e.g. auto-batching queries.

2) Here are some links to information that would help you to decide on per request or per application.

- [Is async HttpClient from .Net 4.5 a bad choice for intensive load applications?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16194054/is-async-httpclient-from-net-4-5-a-bad-choice-for-intensive-load-applications)
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.servicepointmanager.defaultconnectionlimit.aspx

So doing one per application would probably need a reconf of the connection limit.

I have this centralized in my IoC-config, and by default I'm not doing per application. The first "connection" can take a bit longer, but the second has been measured down to milliseconds against Cloudant by other users so that should in general not be an issue.

3)
You can configure the serializer by providing a custom `MyCouchClientBootstrapper` and providing a custom implementation of: https://github.com/danielwertheim/mycouch/blob/master/source/projects/MyCouch.Net45/MyCouchClientBootstrapper.cs#L170

And you also have to extend this guy: https://github.com/danielwertheim/mycouch/blob/master/source/projects/MyCouch.Net45/Serialization/SerializationConfiguration.cs#L9

Feel free to suggest changes that makes this process simpler for you.

Comment: @david in what way?